# how to disable throwing Exceptions or fillInStackTrace() in Java

Tags: java, exception, throwable

I am trying to make my application fast.  It relies on multi threaded http requests. Each time a request gets an error, it seems, the entire program slows down...(even though the requests are on separate threads) I figure this may be due to fillInStackTrace( ) or something like that... I would love to disable it in the Throwable class but I am not able to get into it. Is there a solution ?

The exceptions come from AbstractPlainSocketImpl or SocketInputStream : basically failed internet connections etc.

Comment: It slows down because it is badly written. Also if you say thay internet connection is throwing exceptions that indicates that Sockets are slowing processing down not exceptions nor threads

Comment: That's nice. No. There is no way to change the behavior of the jvm like that.

Comment: So you made new discovery. It is not IO operations that blocks CPU time but stacktraces in exceptions.

Comment: *The exceptions come from AbstractPlainSocketImpl or SocketInputStream : basically failed internet connections etc.* and you didnt think that your internet connection is lagging thus the slowdowns?

Comment: Hi Antonioss, besides being badly written... (much likely)... since these are on separate threads I thought they should not make everything lag.  I think internet while not the fastest is fine. Every thread can wait for info some time.   Tho the slower it goes the more simultaneous threads... which I am sure has a max.